# How can I get a list of only objects that moved in Box2D?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, game-engine, box2d

This should be a fairly easy question to some. It is more of a system design & Box2D API question.

I have custom game engine I am working on and am implementing Box2D as the physics engine. I am trying to **only** update the game objects' transform that have `b2body*` attached to them as a component and that are categorized as kinematic or dynamic (not static). I emphasize the "only" because I am trying to have my overall engine to have good performance. I looked at the Box2D documentation and did not notice a way to get a list or an array of `b2body*` that moved when the `step()` function was called.

So, did I just miss when reading the docs, or should I just keep track of which objects are kinematic and dynamic through a list based data structure and only update those every time I step?

Note: the third type of bodies are static bodies and should not move and do not intend to moved them so I will not update the position.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Link to the Box2D documentation: https://box2d.org/documentation/

Comment: You could check whether the body is awake (https://box2d.org/documentation/classb2_body.html#a697f708427cdf7d31a626e80e694682c) - since a sleeping body will not have moved

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Although I would've hoped to have some sort of list or array of bodies that moved, going through every ```b2Body*``` to see if it is awake to update my game objects' transform would improve performance compared to updating them all regardless of whether they moved or not. I appreciate you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: For anyone visiting this question later on, you can access the list of ```b2Body*``` ever created through the world object ```GetBodyList()``` function and traverse the list and do whatever it is that you need to do.

Comment: You could make two separate body lists, awakeList and asleepList. You can use contactListener to vacate the asleep list (to move elements to the awakeList as they wake on contact), then you only have to iterate over the awakeList, and if a body in the awakeList has been set to sleep then move to asleepList. This means you don't have to iterate over the entire body list. This will go faster if most bodies are asleep.